# Python function keeps on running without breaking even though there is a return

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, dictionary

So this is a basic form of the code I have

```
ans=input("Enter?")
def function():
    #user enters something
    #user enters something 
    #user enters something

    #calculation gets done here

    return("string",number)

while ans!="end":
    dictionary={}
    dictionary[function()[0]]=function()[1]
    ans=input("Enter?")
```

The problem I'm having is for something reason when entering the function it gets to the return and goes back up to the top 2 times without asking me to input ans.

No matter what I put the dictionary only has the last thing I inputted. From what I'm getting, the dictionary is being rewritten instead of the things I want appended being added on. And I am making sure they have different keys. Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `dictionary[function()[0]]=function()[1]`, how many times do you think `function` will be called in order to do that? Why? (Hint: how many times does it *say* `function`?)

Answer (score 4):

In your while loop, you are initialize the dictionary inside the loop, So when loops run, the dictionary also getting initialize. So when you are assigning values to the fresh new dictionary, So you are getting only the last record.

The solution is, Remove the dictionary which is inside the While loop, and initialize that in the outside of the while loop, like this following code

```
dictionary={}
while ans!="end":
  dictionary[function()[0]]=function()[1]
  ans=input("Enter?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your loop the line

```
dictionary = {}
```

creates a new, empty dictionary, so of course your dictionary keeps getting erased. You should create it once, outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems with your code, the first one is already cover in the other answers, the second is this line

```
dictionary[function()[0]]=function()[1]
```

here you call your function twice, one to just use the first element of its return value as the key in the dictionary and then again to use only its second element. Change it for this

```
key, value = function()
dictionary[key] = value
```

this way you only call the function only once per iteration

Comment: Holy shit. That's why my function runs twice. Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to the dictionary outside the while loop. It gets redeclared during every iteration. Should be something like this:

```
dictionary={}
while ans!="end":
    dictionary[function()[0]]=function()[1]
    ans=input("Enter?")
```

**EDIT**:

I ran this code. Note you need to use python3.

```
ans = input("Enter?")
def function():
    #user enters something
    #user enters something 
    #user enters something

    #calculation gets done here
    number = 1
    return("string",number)

dictionary = {}
while ans != "end":
    dictionary[function()[0]] = function()[1]
    ans = input("Enter?")
    print ('ans:', ans)
```

It works fine. Your code asks for use input twice: on the first line and then in the while loop while it's condition is true.

Comment: Okay I tried that, but there is still something wrong with my function. Within my function after the return it should stop running the function and go back into the while loop, but it asks the first input within the function twice before doing that. I have no idea why.